# System of linear differential equations, solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a system of differential equations $\dot{x} = A x$, I know that solutions is given by $x = \exp (At) \cdot x_0$.
Now, I've seen somewhere, that if the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, then the solution can be written as $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} C_i \vec{v}_i e^{\lambda_i t}$, where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$-th eigenvalue, and $\vec{v}_i$ is the eigenvector corresponding to that value. This came up when I was trying to learn how to sketch phase portraits, and this form came up really useful. I want to understand where it came from, so I will be very grateful for explaination.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, you have explicitly
$$
e^{At}=Pe^{Jt}P^{-1},
$$
where $J$ is the diagonal matrix and $P$ is the matrix whose columns are eigenvectors.

Now, for your solution
$$
x(t)=e^{At}x_0=Pe^{Jt}P^{-1}x_0=Pe^{Jt}C=\sum C_i v_i e^{\lambda_i t}.
$$

Comment: Oh, obviously $P^{-1} \cdot x_0$ is a vector of constants... Thank you.